# Do we need closed (or open) sets?

Tags: general-topology, model-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

**Summary**

"open (or closed) topology on $X$"= "join-complete (meet-complete, respectively) bounded lattice on $\mathcal P(X)$, ordered by inclusion."

"theory of topology"="theory of join-complete (meet-complete) bounded lattices."

Complements are optional for the "theory of join-complete (meet-complete) bounded lattices," so "closed sets" (open sets) should be optional for the "theory of topology."

Do we need closed (or open) sets? If not, how do we describe topological properties exclusively in terms of open (closed) sets? i.e. what is "boundary," "connected," "interior," etc. in terms of open (or closed) sets alone?

---

**1. Theory of Topology vs Topological Spaces**

In my experience, topology is usually defined as the study of topological spaces which are in turn defined to be specific kinds of sets ("with additional structure," but unless we want to talk about topologies on proper classes a "structure" is still a kind of set.) I always thought that this was weird because it makes topological properties dependent on the specific choice of set theory - a point which is usually glossed over in "real" topology.

Put differently, if we fix a set theory $\mathsf{ST}$ (with some additional caveats) and let $\mathsf{TS}$ be the the theory obtained from the axioms of topology - whatever those may be - then either $\mathsf{TS}\subseteq\mathsf{ST}$ or $\mathsf{TS}$ is an extension-by-definitions of $\mathsf{ST}$. Knowing this, it's hard to justify the position that topology is anything other than set theory itself. I mean, if we want to be *really* obnoxious about it I guess we could make the claim that the symbols '$\cap$,' '$\cup$,' etc. (or the words 'intersection,' 'union,' etc., for that matter - all symbols in the general sense) which might appear in the axioms of topology do not belong to $\mathsf{ST}\subseteq\langle\in\rangle$, and thus $\mathsf{TS}$ truly constitutes a separate theory from $\mathsf{ST}$. But is anyone really claiming that 'union' in topology *doesn't* refer to the union of sets?

This is made more unusual by the fact that it isn't particularly difficult to create a "proper" theory of topology. For example, we have the second-order theory - which I'll call $\mathsf{LT_2}$ - in the language $\langle\wedge,\vee\rangle$ given by the axioms:

1. $\exists x\forall y((x\wedge y=x)\land(x\vee y=y))$, i.e. the empty set exists (is open)
2. $\exists x\forall y((x\wedge y=y)\land(x\vee y=x))$, i.e. the universal set exists (is open)*
3. $\forall X\exists x\forall y(X(y)\implies((x\wedge y=y)\land (x\vee y=x)))$, i.e. the arbitrary union of sets exists (is open)

*this axiom is redundant

(note that closure under intersection is guaranteed by the fact that $\wedge$ is a binary function symbol, hence $x\wedge y$ is a term and $\forall x\forall y\exists!z(x\wedge y=z)$ is a [trivial] theorem)

The standard models ("lattice topologies") are obtained from the obvious interpretation $\wedge\to\cap,\vee\to\cup$ with the domain being a topology (the set of open sets) on the underlying set of the corresponding topological space. For example, if

$$E=\left\{\bigcup_{S\in I}S:I\subseteq\{(\alpha,\beta)\subseteq\Bbb R:\alpha\le\beta\}\right\}$$

Then $(E,\cap,\cup)\vDash\mathsf{LT_2}$ (it is, in fact, the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ dressed as a lattice.) These models aren't isomorphic to conventional topological spaces but we can construct something akin to isomorphism by way of functions $F_X:\{(\tau_X,\cap,\cup):\bigcup\tau_X=X, (\tau_X,\cap,\cup)\vDash\mathsf{LT_2}\}\to\mathbf{Top}(X)$, where $\mathbf{Top}(X)$ is the set of all topological spaces on $X$, such that:

$$F_X(\tau_X,\cap,\cup)=(X,\tau_X)$$

The union of all such functions is a class function [also a functor, I think?] which maps lattice topologies to topological spaces.

This may or may not happen to be the way that pointless topology is done - I wouldn't know; but it doesn't really matter since the whole point of this was to show that we can create a theory of topology with minimal effort.

**2. Topology vs Closed (or Open) Sets**

While we can show that $\mathsf{LT_2}$ (or any other theory) is essentially the "theory of topology" there is one noteworthy distinction. In $\mathsf{TS}$ we can prove the existence ($\pm$uniqueness) of any set whose existence we can prove in $\mathsf{ST}$. In particular - if $\mathsf{ST}$ has [relative] complements, as is the case for $\mathsf{ST}=\mathsf{ZFC}$ - we can define *closed* sets without departing from $\mathsf{TS}$ (actually, this isn't true, but you have to go out of your way to make sure that $\mathsf{TS}$ *doesn't* admit complements.)

This is not the case for $\mathsf{LT_2}$, where the only sets that exist are open sets. We can readily see this by looking at finite topologies. Consider, for example, the set

$$A=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{c\},\{a,c\},\{a,b,c\}\}$$

Clearly $\mathcal A=(A,\cap,\cup)$ is a structure for $\mathsf{LT_2}$, but the closed set $\{b\}$ is excluded from the domain. Of course, we can still talk about $\{b\}$ as an object of $\mathcal A$ within $\mathsf{TS}$, but we can infer nothing about its behaviour from $\mathsf{LT_2}$.

This, together with the fact that $\mathsf{LT_2}$ suffices to characterize all topological spaces (to the extent that any topological space is characterized by $\mathsf{TS}$) leads me to question whether or not closed sets (or open sets, if we use a closed set definition) were even necessary in the first place.

It is not hard to *add* closed sets to $\mathsf{LT_2}$ (or any other theory) - simply add complements and the predicates '$O$' and '$C$' with the axiom $\forall x(O(x)\iff C(x'))$, where $x'$ is the complement of $x$. But it would be much more interesting to find out that closed sets (or open sets) are redundant.

Comment: Maybe you would like to read about the theory of locales, also known as "pointless topology".

Comment: I guess developing topology within set theory facilitates most of the reasoning we actually want to do about topological spaces, since set theory lets us talk about "higher-order" objects like maps between spaces, homotopies of such maps, etc. If you start with something like $\mathsf{LT_2}$, then all of the useful/interesting work will take place in your model theory and therefore still require a choice of set theory (or some kind of higher category theory), if I understand correctly. Maybe I'm missing your point.

Comment: Relatedly, have you heard of [homotopy type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory)?

Comment: @Karl You're right that most of the work takes place in the model theory. This all started because the three Topologists that I know seem to think that "topology," as a subject, exists separately from set theory. I don't think this viewpoint is correct, but I'm willing to play the "what if" game, so I spent an afternoon trying to devise a theory of topology, and noticed that I was missing closed sets despite having all the same models. Since we can describe the class of all topological spaces this way, I figure there's a way to go without closed sets entirely.

Comment: @Karl I heard of HoTT. From what I gather, it's a terrifying and powerful form of witchcraft.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now. According to the Wikipedia article on pointless topology, there are locales that don’t correspond to classical topological spaces, which suggests that we do need more set-theoretic structure than what's encoded by the lattice in order to characterize topological spaces.

Comment: What your three topologist friends probably mean when they say that "topology exists separately from set theory" is not that you can do topology without talking about sets, but rather than the theorems of topology do not really depend on foundational questions about our axioms of set theory. That is, if we swapped out ZFC set theory for some other foundational system, and built topology on the sets in that foundation, the subject of topology (its methods, theorems, and general flavor) wouldn't change much. Now if "topology" means "general / point-set topology", this view is wrong! (continued)

Comment: There are an enormous number of natural statements in general topology that turn out to be independent from ZFC, and there's a whole subfield of [set-theoretic topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_topology) that investigates questions of topology that are highly sensitive to our underlying set theory. On the other hand, the field of algebraic topology, where we restrict to "nice" topological spaces and study them with algebraic methods, is (typically, but not always) less "bound up" with set theory. Are your topologist friends algebraic topologists?

Comment: @AlexKruckman "Are your topologist friends algebraic topologists?" \*sigh\* yes. Well two of them anyway, the other one just doesn't like to think about axiomatic set theory. Still, the independence of the "high level" theorems of general topology from foundations should mean that we can build a "naked" theory of topology in the same way we can build arithmetic, geometry, or group theory. Certainly topology requires less than the whole of ZFC? But not every set theory can carry topology, either. At the very least, we need to be able to implement union, intersection and empty set.